# Cast videos in queue by Chromecast stop playing video automatically after some time

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Cast video using Chromecast in a queue is working fine. As per my requirement, it's need to play video constantly for hours on the screen. For that  i get bunch of video urls from server for 5 to 10 videos. When 2 video are remain i get new bunch and i append in a queue. Videos are with the length around 40 to 50 seconds.

It continues play for about 45 to 60 min not more than that. It stops than.

I want it to play for hours...

Can any one Help me to come out from this issue. Any help will be useful for me.

Here is my code to play queue.

```
public void queuePlay(ArrayList<CastModel> data) {

    ArrayList<MediaQueueItem> queueList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);

        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, data.get(i).vTitle);
        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, data.get(i).vName);
        mediaMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(data.get(i).vImage)));

        JSONObject extraData = null;

        try {

            extraData = getJsonOfObject(data.get(i));
            if (extraData == null)
                extraData = new JSONObject();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "queuePlay: exception " + e.toString());
        }


        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(data.get(i).vVideo)
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("videos/mp4")
                .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                .setCustomData(extraData)
                .setStreamDuration(30 * 1000)
                .build();
        MediaQueueItem item = new MediaQueueItem.Builder(mediaInfo).build();
        queueList.add(item);
    }


    MediaQueueItem[] queueArray = new MediaQueueItem[queueList.size()];
    queueArray = queueList.toArray(queueArray);

    remoteMediaClient = sessionManager.getCurrentCastSession().getRemoteMediaClient();
    remoteMediaClient.queueLoad(queueArray, 0, REPEAT_MODE_REPEAT_OFF, null);

    remoteMediaClient.addListener(new RemoteMediaClient.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusUpdated() {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Hold for a while
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            MediaStatus mMediaStatus = remoteMediaClient.getMediaStatus();
            if (mMediaStatus != null && mMediaStatus.getQueueItems() != null) {

                if (queueItemPlayedPosition < mMediaStatus.getCurrentItemId()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onStatusUpdated: Delete video " + queueItemPlayedPosition);
                    updateCastList(false);
                    queueItemPlayedPosition++;
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "onStatusUpdated getCurrentItemId " + remoteMediaClient.getMediaStatus().getCurrentItemId() + " *** onStatusUpdated: getQueueItemCount *** " + mMediaStatus.getQueueItemCount());
            } 

        }

        @Override
        public void onMetadataUpdated() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onQueueStatusUpdated() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreloadStatusUpdated() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSendingRemoteMediaRequest() {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't played with Cast SDK a lot but found this [Autoplay & Queueing APIs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/autoplay) which might provide what you're looking for as it mentions ways to play videos continuously using autoplay.